# Is a fuel that reacts with another to form hydrogen for fueling aircraft possible?

Tags: jet-engine, fuel

Hydrogen is the most abundant element in the universe and has great properties when reacting with oxygen for use as a fuel. Yet here on Earth, its production is prohibitively expensive, its storage without wastage is almost impossible because its molecules are so small no know substance or material can store it safely without leaks. Not to mention safety, as it is highly explosive.

Given its energy density, the above mentioned problems and other inherent problems I did not mention with using hydrogen as a fuel for aircraft, is it possible to come up with a compound or two compounds that can be safely stored in two tanks and have an efficient energy to weight ratio, such that when they react by mixture or process, they produce enough hydrogen to power airliners at the same rate or much more efficiently than with regular fuel?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_production Take your pick.

Comment: Whatever your ingredient is, you might as well just burn them directly, minus the incombustible ones like water.

Comment: What actual aviation-related problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That's essentially how some liquid fueled rockets work. Which is not a great choice of fuel for a passenger plane.

Comment: @verandaguy Im hoping one day the carbon footprint is lowered in aviation, that is the one industry encountering the most difficulty in technical challenges

Comment: what has your research shown you so far?  When we ask a question (see [ask]) , we should do some initial research first.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast 

Chemical hydrogen storage materials like hydrazine, borohydrides etc. are considered potential candidates for this purpose (1).

Nanoparticles, nanoalloys & functionalized nanoparticles are extensively trailed as catalysts for efficient on-demand hydrogen generation from those materials. We are, however, yet to reach a stage where the hydrogen generation is rapid enough to be used in applications such as in an aircraft.

Comment: Your title question is rather at odds with the rambling prose in your question's body text.  I have a sugestion.  Re write it so that you clearly take the pithy title, explore some factors in the body, and then actually state the question in the body of your question.  And then, if you have an answer, write an answer to your own question.  Beyond that: the title question is an issue that both automotive and airline industry folks, and various scientists and engineers, have been intrigued by for about 40 years.  (See also fusion for electric power). Your question is, as posed, Too Broad.

Comment: Well, yes.  You react the hydrogen with carbon to form moderately long-chain hydrocarbons, say 12-15 carbons, which conveniently form a fairly dense liquid at ambient temperatures.  Then you react those hydrocarbons with atmospheric oxygen to run your jet engine, elimininating the need for a second tank.  Of course if you want to burn your fuel at a high rate, you can add a liquid oxygen supply to the system, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-IC

Comment: Methane can be used to produce hydrogen, and also burned to produce superheated steam (1,000°C required) needed by this process. However you will get more range by just burning methane in much simpler engine.

Comment: @h22, the goal is hydrogen production as an alternative to carbon, any combustion that results in CO2 is undesirable, if perhaps the hydrogen stored in methane or some other compound is produced with a requisite or higher energy density than current fossil fuel with some other less harmful carbon by-product then that would be a step in the right direction for carbon emissions, but then again an even better compound would have to be produced removing that by product because it has unnecessary weight and has to be carried around..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chemical reactions to produce hydrogen (or hydrogen-rich gas mixtures -- acids and metal, steam over red hot iron, or coking coal) were commonly used to produce lifting gas from the early days of ballooning until hydrogen was phased out for dirigibles.

Except for coking, these aren't practical to produce hydrogen for fuel (and coal gas has too many other things in it to be readily converted to a carbon-neutral fuel).  The energy required for the process (heating iron red hot and boiling water, heating coal red hot in a retort, or producing strong nitric or sulfuric acid) is MUCH more than the resulting gas will produce when burned in an engine.  Even reforming (converting light hydrocarbons directly to hydrogen with catalysts) is more useful for the low consumption of a fuel cell than for an engine that will want hundreds of kilos of gas per minute.

Direct electrolysis is currently the most energy-efficient method of producing hydrogen in quantity, but it completely fails to overcome the other practical issues with hydrogen as a fuel (low density, storage problems, effects on materials).  The combination of power density requirement and mass limitations for flight mean we'll probably be burning synthetic hydrocarbons that are direct replacements  for gasoline and kerosene (but hopefully carbon-neutral) for decades before we can completely eliminate combustion engines in aircraft -- if it's ever practical to do so.